# What is the best way to dynamically set 'where' conditions on PHP select query?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database which holds calendar events. On handle_events.php?load=1, I want the file to echo all the events. If things like 'start=20190121' or 'end=20190121' are appended to the url, I want the file to echo events only that are in this timeline. The solutions I have thought of were:

1. write the entire query in each if-else for every possible settings.
   -> This would be almost impossible if the options increase.
2. set

   $query="select from sometable where first condition"

   and append "AND option=value" on each option addition
   -> This would be acceptable on multiple options, but what if there is not a single necessary condition? then the statement would be like "~ where AND option=value" and would raise a syntax error.

These two ways both have drawbacks and look somewhat primitive. Would there be a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Are you expecting the url query to be two possible states? If so I have shown a solution below. If not I think the question in unclear

Comment: @Burndogz I mean if I want a few different restrictions to fetch data at different situations, what would be the best way to include that restrictions only to the query? Refering to my example, the query can be appended by start=20190121 or end=20190121 or both: start=20190121&end=20190121.

Comment: ‘start=20190121' or 'end=20190121'   Or your default state...  Yes, use conditional statements based on the url parameters and have properly associated queries.  It’s the best way as those are the literal variables in the condition you are looking to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a conditional statement that checks If the $_GET[‘your date’] is present and the format your query accordingly.

```
if(isset($_GET[‘start’])) {
 Show one query condition
} else {
 Show default state of query
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$where=""
if(isset($_GET[‘start’]))
{
if($where=='')
{
$where.=" option=value"
}
else
{
$where.="AND  option=value"
}
}
```